# Meaning of the word "kernel" in this context.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, terminology

I'm confused about the (maybe abuse of) use of the word $kernel$ in certain contexts. Let us look to a concrete example. [Here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/%7Eheil/metricnote/chap8.pdf) in the definition 8.1.1 we find a definition for an integral operator **with kernel $k$** to be $L_k(f) = \int k(x,y)f(y)dy$.

Clearly as stated there, this *kernel is not related* to the nullspace of $L_k$. Hence, the question is really simple:

**Why the use of the word kernel in this context?**

Might this be related to some kind of *"zero"* that I might be ignoring? Or is this just a more semantic question?

I have also seen the word kernel in machine learning problems-related fields. But none of these "*kernels*" seem to be related to a nullspace.

Comment: It seems to be "kernel" in analysis is unrelated to the well known notion from linear algebra, and it is connected to transforms of several types.

Comment: ["One of the miseries of life is that everybody names things a little bit wrong, and so it makes everything a little harder to understand"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKWGGDXe5MA&feature=youtu.be&t=296) -- Richard Feynman

Comment: There is no connection between the two uses of the word, besides the common meaning of being "at the root of". Both were "forged" around 1900.

Comment: @JeanMarie If you wouldn't mind, could you expand that comment into an answer (ideally with a reference) so this is no longer unanswered?