# Heat kernel and Markov kernel are 'kernels' in which sense

Tags: abstract-algebra, partial-differential-equations, terminology, definition

In which sense the [Heat kernel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel#:%7E:text=The%20heat%20kernel%20represents%20the,point%20at%20time%20t%20%3D%200.) and [Markov kernels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_kernel#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20a%20Markov,with%20a%20finite%20state%20space.) are 'kernels'? Is there any motivation/ intuition for the choice of such name? In particular, is there any relation to algebraic concept of a [kernel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(algebra))?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [Meaning of the word "kernel" in this context.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4147445/26369), but I can't vote to close this as a duplicate since no one wrote an answer to that question either.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4147445/305862)